# What's the difference between a Trigger and a DataTrigger?

Tags: wpf, triggers, datatrigger

They seem the same. Is there a significant difference? I think I am missing something.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the different triggers in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239855/what-are-the-different-triggers-in-wpf)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

A regular `Trigger` only responds to dependency properties.

A `DataTrigger` can be triggered by any .NET property (by setting its `Binding` property).  However, its setters can still target only dependency properties.

Comment: If this is the sole difference, then why would one use the regular trigger?

Comment: `Trigger` is more convenient to work with when you're binding to properties in the View.

Comment: @SeanU why, what is more convenient?

Answer (score 33):

Another difference is that a `DataTrigger` can be bound to another control, a StaticResource, etc etc.

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger 
      Binding="{Binding SomeProperty, 
                        ElementName=someOtherControl" 
      Value="Derp">
      <!-- etc -->
```

You can only examine the instance on which the style is set when using a `Trigger`.  For example, a `Trigger` applied to a Button can inspect the value of `IsPressed`, but it would not be able to inspect the (for example) `Text` value of a `TextBox` on the same form if you wished to disable the `Button` if the `TextBox` was empty.

Answer (score 19):

The short answer (as I'm about to sleep)- A trigger works on [dependency properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.aspx) (typically GUI properties) whereas data triggers can be triggered by any .NET property (typically a property in a ViewModel that implements [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)).

Comment: Have you woken up yet? I'd love the full answer :)

Comment: To put it succinctly, if you want to trigger off of a UI element's dependency property (e.g. CheckBox's IsEnabled, IsChecked, etc.) that is on your View, then you should use a normal Trigger (a.k.a. PropertyTrigger). If you want to trigger off of a property on your View Model, then you should use a Data Trigger.