# WPF Trigger Properties

Tags: wpf, xaml, properties, triggers

I am fairly new to WPF and I am currently working with [`triggers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.trigger.aspx).  I have a question regarding a *simple trigger*.  By *simple trigger*, I mean one that watches for a change in a [`dependency property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.aspx) and uses a [`setter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.setter.aspx) to change the style.

Example:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Control.IsFocused" Value ="True">
        <Setter Property=" Control.Foreground" Value =" DarkRed" />
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

All examples I have seen have used the following [`trigger properties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.trigger.property.aspx):

- `<Trigger Property="Control.IsFocused" Value ="True">`
- `<Trigger Property="Control.IsMouseOver" Value ="True">`
- `<Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value ="True">`

**Question**:
Are these the *only* trigger properties available? If not, what others exist?

I have searched online but to no avail. Maybe someone could shed some light on this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

These are not the only properties that you can use in your `Triggers`, however, they are common examples because they are easily understandable and easy to demonstrate.

In truth, you can have your `Trigger` watch any `DependencyProperty`, but because it is "triggered" when the value changes (and matches the `Value` you tell it to watch for), it only makes sense to use properties that will change at runtime, often from user action (such as focus, mouse over, pressed, etc).  Only certain `DependencyProperties` actual change value under these circumstances, so not all of them make sense to use in `Triggers`.

Microsoft has added several `DependencyProperties` to the standard controls so that you can easily create triggers based on changes.  However you can also create your own controls with your own `DependencyProperties` and have triggers that respond when your custom `DependencyProperties` change.

Keep in mind, `PropertyTriggers` are only one flavor of `Trigger` in WPF.  There are also `EventTriggers` and `DataTriggers` and `MultiTriggers`.  These other triggers fire based on events or changes in data, or in the case of `MultiTriggers` multiple property (or data) values.

Is there something specific you're trying to do with `Triggers`?  [This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239855/what-are-the-different-triggers-in-wpf) provides a good explanation of what each type of trigger does.

Comment: I forgot `EventTriggers` and `MultiTriggers` in my answer because I almost never use them. Thanks for reminding me! :)

Comment: :).  Agreed @Rachel, `EventTriggers` are far less common.  I've probably only used them a handful of times.

Answer (score 9):

There are multiple types of triggers in WPF, but the two most commonly used are regular `Triggers` and `DataTriggers`

Both types of triggers will watch a value, and when it changes to match the specified `Value` then they apply your Style Setters.

**Regular triggers** can be used for any Dependency Property of the object. This includes properties like `Text`, `Visibility`, `Background`, etc in addition to the more commonly triggered properties that you specified: `IsFocused`, `IsMouseOver`, and `IsPressed`.

Note that per the [MSDN page about Trigger.Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.trigger.property.aspx), you don't need to specify the class name prefix if the Style or Template containing the trigger has it's `TargetType` property set

An easy way to remember it is if you can bind the property, you can set a Trigger on it.

**DataTriggers** are triggers that watch a bound value instead of a Dependency Property. They allow you to watch a bound expression, and will react when that binding evaluates equal to your Value.

For example, you could set a `DataTrigger` on `"{Binding Value}"` or `"{Binding ElementName=MyTextBox, Path=IsChecked}"`. You can even use `Converters` with DataTriggers, such as

```
<DataTrigger
    Binding="{Binding SomeInt, Converter={StaticResource IsGreaterThanZero}}"
    Value="True">
```

Comment: So for **regular triggers**, there is no property like... `Control.IsMouseDown`?

Comment: @Dom I just added an update to my answer. You don't need to include the class name prefix on the triggered property if you have the `TargetType` property set on the Style or Template containing the trigger. So if your `TargetType` has an `IsMouseDown` property, then you can set a trigger on `IsMouseDown` instead of using `Control.IsMouseDown`

Comment: Don't forget `EventTriggers`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for better experience with trigger in wpf.

```
<Window x:Class="DataBinding.Trigger2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Trigger2" Height="500" Width="500">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Tahoma"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"></Setter>

        </Style.Setters>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Purple"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkCyan"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Franklin Gothic"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="25"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Heavy"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="400"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Violet"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Times New Roman"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Thin"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="250"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="250"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Button>It's a Magic.</Button>
```