# Set a trigger for first item in the list

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers

My question is a follow-up question of this other post: [What are the different triggers in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239855/what-are-the-different-triggers-in-wpf)

I want to set a trigger that triggers if the item is the first one in a listview (so I can add a extra text). Which type of trigger shall I use?

here is my code:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Name="contactList" Margin="0,0,0,0">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <WrapPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger <!-- what do I have to put here so it triggers when the item is the first one in the list? -->>
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value=" - this is the first item in the list!!"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#7f8c8d"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </WrapPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use a `DataTrigger` with a `MultiBinding` and a converter for this bad boy. Check it out.

First, your converter...

```
class IsFirstItemConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ObservableCollection<NamedObject> col = (ObservableCollection<NamedObject>)values[0];
        if (col[0].Equals(values[1]))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now reference it in App.xaml...

```
<local:IsFirstItemConverter x:Key="isFirstItem"/>
```

Now for the meat...

```
<ListView x:Name="lv" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <!--Text property moved to here-->
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Value="True">
                                <DataTrigger.Binding>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource isFirstItem}">
                                        <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                            <Binding ElementName="lv" Path="ItemsSource"/>
                                            <Binding/>
                                        </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </DataTrigger.Binding>
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="First item"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Notice you'll have to move the setter for the `Text` property into the style. Since explicit declarations in the control override any property setters in styles, you wont ever see the effect of the trigger unless you move it as shown. Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks gengis_jhan. I've done this but it triggers an unhandled exception in the Convert method. This is the exception: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in KnxPmpApp.exe

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.ListView'.  It happens in this line: ListView lv = (ListView)values[0];

Comment: Are your bindings in the order shown above? What are the objects being passed in via the values[] array?

Comment: values[0] is -  [0] {DependencyProperty.UnsetValue} object {MS.Internal.NamedObject}
 values[1] is the first Contact

Comment: Is the `x:Name` attribute of your `ListView` identical to the `ElementName` property of the first binding?

Comment: It wasn't. That was the issue. Solved :) Thank you!!

Comment: @chincheta73 You're very welcome. Thanks for the opportunity to help! If you found my answer helpful, could you please mark it as accepted? Cheers!

Comment: I have realised one issue: when I move the items in the list, so I change the order, the binding doesn't work. I have added another DataTrigger with the False condition that sets the TextBox value to "" but still doesn´t work. It seems like it only checks the condition for the "moved" item in the list but not for the other items. But if item0 is moved to position4 (for example), the old item1 is now item0 and therefore needs to be triggered.

Comment: What type of collection is your `ItemsSource` property bound to?

Comment: ObservableCollection

Comment: Updated the answer. It should properly respond now.

Comment: Still same issue. But something strange: I was setting the items source of the listview on code-behind on this way: lv.ItemsSource = mContactList; If I do it in the XAML file, exactly like it appears on you code, the lv doesn´t show the items (but they are there cause I have put a breakpoint and checked it)

Comment: Does your `ObservableCollection` property use PropertyChanged? Is it a `DependencyProperty`?

Comment: It may be helpful to post a new question with the current state of your code. Get some fresh eyes on the thing as well.

Comment: One more thing, `lv.Items.Refresh` should be called after you update the items list. The bindings should then update correctly.

Comment: Okey, that last thing fixed the issue :) thank you again !!

Comment: Sure thing! Good luck.