# Where can I find a complete list of Triggers for Controls in WPF/XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, styles

I am trying to find out which triggers work on what control. Unfortunately VS2015 still does not support inteliSense when trying to define Triggers for my controls.

```
<Trigger Property="IntellisenseIsNotHelping" Value="true">
```

I tried the MSDN documentation but the triggers listed there all start with **On-InsertTriggerHere**. Whereas the triggers I use all start with **Is- InsertTriggerHere**.

Comment: You should be able to trigger on any property of a control. A control's properties are listed on its MSDN page.

Comment: Thanks Clemens! That exactly what I was looking for. Have a nice day chap!

Answer (score 1):

[What are the different triggers in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239855/what-are-the-different-triggers-in-wpf)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.triggerbase(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Those are types of triggers and the tirgger class. The triggers defined for controls can be found under the properties of the control, like Clemens commented. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

**You should be able to trigger on any property of a control. A control's properties are listed on its MSDN page. – Clemens 20 hours ago**