# Change particular button Background color on Mouse over in xaml wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am struggling with the issue for last three days.
I have to change particular Button background color on mouse over and Button Content should be delete, But i got issue that all button changed if i am hovering of button.
I put my design In resource dictionary 
Below is my design code

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
     <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                  <Storyboard>`<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BaseShape" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ButtonHoverBackgroundBrush}" />
                         </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                         <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BaseShape" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
               <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ButtonHoverBorderBrush}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonHighlight" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                     </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                 </Storyboard>
          </VisualState> </VisualStateGroup></VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>'
                             <Border x:Name="BaseShape" CornerRadius="10" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="ButtonHighlight" Margin="1" RadiusX="9" RadiusY="9" Stroke="{StaticResource ButtonHoverHighlightBorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Opacity="0" />
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusedVisualElement" Stroke="{StaticResource ButtonFocusedBorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="1" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Opacity="0" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" Fill="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" IsHitTestVisible="false" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Opacity="0" />

<Button Content="delete" Name="xyz" Width="70"Margin="0,65,59,4" HorizontalAlignment="Right">      
           </Button>`
```

and
Xaml
File with design is
and i need fix only design side not in code behind

Comment: Please provide your `XAML` of the `Button`. I think this will be pretty simple with `Trigger`.

Comment: Since your button doesnt have a Style defined, I guess (and guessing is all I can, since you didnt provide enough Information) that your Style, where your definition for the VisualStateManager lies, is configured to be applied to all buttons. Something like ``<Style TargetType="Button">``, but it should be ``<Style Key="MagicButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">`` and ``<Button Style={StaticResource MagicButtonStyle"}>``

Comment: Also vote just to use a trigger

Comment: Ok I am giving you whole code Just please help me i tried a lot over net and also tried in Blend...I used trigger and Data Trigger but now worked ..Please check my below code i put in Resource file,If any button exist in code that below style will automatically applied and what i need is i have two button in multiple files both button have Content such as Submit and Close ..By default button style given in Resource file Automatically set to Button but what i want is .Submit should be orange and Close should be Red and once i mouse hover Orange should be orange but Red should change into white

Comment: <Style x:Key="BaseButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonBackgroundBrush1}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonBorderBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3" />
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2">
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>

Comment: <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter> <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding  Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="DELETE">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#990000"></Setter>

Comment: </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding  Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Log out">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#990000"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
               
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

Comment: <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseButtonStyle}" TargetType="Button"> <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"></Setter> <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
 <Setter Property="Template"> <Setter.Value>                  <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid><VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
   <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="ChangeLogoutButtonColor">
                                        <Storyboard>

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming by "Button background color on mouse over and Button Content should be delete" you mean that you want to change the colour and hide the content while your mouse is over the button. If so, why don't you do something like this

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="SkyBlue"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="SkyBlue"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

While it doesn't delete the content it sets the foreground and background to the same colour so it is hidden from the user.

**Edited to address your comments**

You seem to be trying to use a DataTrigger; as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239855/what-are-the-different-triggers-in-wpf) suggests Triggers are ideal for making changes on things like OnMouseOver and DataTriggers are ideal for making changes on data changes. So unless I'm missing something, you should be using a Trigger not a DataTrigger.

An obvious solution to your style-variation problem is to create a default style with most of your styling in and then a second style that overrides the changing elements. In this case your second style would give it the "hide my text on mouse over" behaviour.

Your default style could be something like this

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonDefaultStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And your second style could be something like this

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonHideTextOnMouseOverStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonDefaultStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Then you'd use them like this

```
<Button Content="First Button" Style="{StaticResource ButtonDefaultStyle}"/>
<Button Content="Second Button" Style="{StaticResource ButtonDefaultStyle}"/>
<Button Content="Delete" Style="{StaticResource ButtonHideTextOnMouseOverStyle}"/>
```

In the ButtonDefaultStyle cases the white text on a blue background is changed to blue text on a white background on mouse over. In the ButtonHideTextOnMouseOverStyle case the white text on a blue background is changed to white text on a white background on mouse over.

The full example is here

```
<Window x:Class="Button_Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Button_Test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ButtonDefaultStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="ButtonHideTextOnMouseOverStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonDefaultStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Buttons"/>
        <Button Content="First Button" Style="{StaticResource ButtonDefaultStyle}"/>
        <Button Content="Second Button" Style="{StaticResource ButtonDefaultStyle}"/>
        <Button Content="Delete" Style="{StaticResource ButtonHideTextOnMouseOverStyle}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: See Below code  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsMouseOver, ElementName=delete}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>

Comment: And my OutPut Is All Three Button Same Background White and Border brush red..I only Want Delete button should be white ..Not all

Comment: <Button Content="Delete" Name="delete" Width="50" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,70.121,170.028,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:LayoutOverrides="Height"/>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Kii" Width="50" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="186.349,70.121,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:LayoutOverrides="Height"/>
        <Button x:Name="button1" Content="ZeKiillo" Width="50" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="82.075,70.121,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></Button>

Comment: And i Don't want to hide any thing i just want to "Change my only Delete Button On mouse hover when multiple button are in same style